# How to Launch another application from My Android app Activity

Tags: java, android

I want to start launch `facebook` from my application I have tried the below code

```
 public void text(String MessageBody) {
        
        public void text(String MessageBody) { 
        try { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "salam its working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); 
            if(MessageBody=="facebook") { 
                Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.camera"); 
                startActivity(intent); 
            } 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    }
```

This is working fine from activity class but I am looking for a way to run the same code in non-activity class.

Comment: Strings should be always compared with `equals()` method not with `==`.

Comment: @PradeepSimha not **always**, but most of the times, and it is best practice to do so. By the way **it's not working** does not mean anything, in which way is it not working ? Does it compile ? Does it throw an exception ? Any error message ?

Comment: not exception dear its working well and also show toast but not start activity from not Broadcastreciver class

Comment: this method working well in activity class but no result from non activity class when i call

Comment: Was it because of the `==` ?

Comment: Many of the things you are trying to do require a valid Context.  If you don't necessarily have an Activity instance initialized by Android, you won't be able to use that as your context.  Instead, you should probably call methods on your BroadcastReceiver's or Service's Context.

Comment: i change to equals() still problem this method only invoked from activity class but not non-activity class :(

Comment: when i call from non activity class its toast but not start the activity :'(

Comment: now when i call this method its generate null pointer exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was error of context ,now its working in when i start activity method in non activity class

```
    Context c;
    Toast.makeText(context, message1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intentt =pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
    context.startActivity(intentt);
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx5Vg.jpg)